# how to use asp.net core web api sqlite database in a host server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Im using Visual Studio Mac.
Im working on a asp.net core web api with sqlite database.
it works fine in localhost.
but doesn't work on host server. it gives 500 internal server error.
I published it from a windows visual studio as ftp.
I think my internal error is because of my sqlite configuration. 
its:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite("Filename=./MyData.db"));
```

I think this configuration doesn't work in host and I have no idea about it.
I just published it.
 please help me with it.

Comment: Check the exception that is thrown on the server. It should give you direction for the fix.

Comment: it gives me this error : SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: MyTable'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to:

- Instead of using relative path on filename config, try using the absolute path.

Note: If it works, I'd recommend you to use

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(String.Format("Filename={0}/MyData.db", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory));
```

As you're using './MyData.db', I believe 'AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory' is going to be enough, other than that, you must use your correct file location.

[Solved]

- Add this statement to the method you're calling.

  try 
      { 
      //YOURCODE 
      } 
      catch (Exception e) 
      { 
       return StatusCode(500, $"An error has ocurred. Ex: e.InnerException.Message}"); }
- Check the error message (no such table: MyTable)
- Create the table.

Problem solved.

Best Regards

Comment: Your app generates any kind of log? Can you post here?

Comment: I published it on a host. And I test it with postman. It only gives me 500 internal server error. But other requests that dont related to the database work fine.

Comment: I think you should output the error that is happening so we can have a better idea on what's going on.

Comment: Would you please tell me how to do that. I have no idea. Thanks.

Comment: Add the following try catch on the method you're calling.                  
            try
            {
                //YOURCODE
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, $"An error has ocurred. Ex: {e.InnerException.Message}");
            }

Comment: this is the error message: SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: MyTable'

Comment: Here we go. You're not having problems with the config. You are probably trying to use a table that does not exists.

Comment: No problem. Glad you have been able to solve it. Can you please vote for my answer. Have a good one.

Comment: Sure. I will. Thanx.